# Can't inline Bokeh in IPython

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, bokeh

I have the latest Bokeh and IPython installed, and I try running the following:
(all of these imports are relevant later on in the code)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as itt
import bokeh.plotting as bk
bk.output_notebook()

xs = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
ys = [x**2 for x in xs]

p.line(xs, ys, line_width=2)
p.circle(xs,ys)
bk.show(p)
```

After running these 2 cells, I get:

> Javascript error adding output!  ReferenceError: Bokeh is not defined
>   See your browser Javascript console for more details.

So, I run the console and see this:

```
ReferenceError: Bokeh is not defined Stack trace: @http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20150304125302 line 4 > eval:1:1 .globalEval@http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20150304125302:4:4231 .domManip@http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20150304125302:5:21389 .append@http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20150304125302:5:18980 OutputArea.prototype._safe_append@http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js?v=20150304125302:414:13 OutputArea.prototype.append_display_data@http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js?v=20150304125302:534:13 OutputArea.prototype.append_output@http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js?v=20150304125302:320:13 OutputArea.prototype.handle_output@http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js?v=20150304125302:234:9 CodeCell.prototype.get_callbacks/<.iopub.output@http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/codecell.js?v=20150304125302:456:21 Kernel.prototype._handle_output_message@http://localhost:8888/static/services/kernels/kernel.js?v=20150304125302:997:13 .proxy/i@http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20150304125302:4:5486 Kernel.prototype._handle_iopub_message@http://localhost:8888/static/services/kernels/kernel.js?v=20150304125302:1024:13 Kernel.prototype._finish_ws_message@http://localhost:8888/static/services/kernels/kernel.js?v=20150304125302:866:17 .proxy/i@http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20150304125302:4:5486 deserialize@http://localhost:8888/static/services/kernels/serialize.js?v=20150304125302:60:13 Kernel.prototype._handle_ws_message@http://localhost:8888/static/services/kernels/kernel.js?v=20150304125302:857:9 .proxy/i@http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20150304125302:4:5486 outputarea.js:416
```

Before seeing this, bk.show(p) displayed a distorted plot, saying "Hello Word", but all the buttons were deformed.
matplotlib works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i restarted the system a few times, and started a new notebook, and suddenly everything works. i'm guessing the issue was with one of the imports, but i'm not 100% sure. now everything works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

This issues was addressed in https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2024 which moved the code that loads BokehJS into `output_notebook` instead of just trying to do it when `bokeh` is imported. However, I would still recommend putting `bk.output_notebook` in *its own ipython cell with nothing else.* I am going to update the documentation to reflect this recommendation soon. The issue is that Bokeh uses IPython's "publish" mechanism to load itself, and if you put other things in a cell that also have output, it can interfere with that. Thats just the way IPython notebook works, there's not really anything else to do but to suggest putting `output_notebook` on its own, so it is output is guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: At the moment (current release 0.8.2), this is available only from master or using the dev build (for more info about how to install it look here: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/bokeh/9KmaMqZAb8w/SaLb67QDWjMJ )

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Javascript` function loaded in `IPython.core.display`, ommit it and re-run your code.